# Integral as: martingale or local martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I wonder when a stochastic integral is a martingale or a local martingale. Let's assume that we have a process:

$X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^{t} a_s ds + \int_0^t b_s dW_s$

Is this kind of integral a martingale or local martingale. Is this connected with the integral $\int_{0}^{t} a_s ds$? (if it is present, the process is a martigale and in the opposite situation it is a local martingale?). What would happen if we have some proces $Y_t$ and our $X_t$ looks like that:

$X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(Y_s) ds + \int_0^t f(Y_s) dW_s$

I would love to read something more about those properties. I will appreciate any link/paper related to this topic.

Comment: What if $a_s=s$?

Comment: Your "first" process $X_t$ is a martingale iff $a:=0$.